# In Auto Layout, I set up labels that shouldn't grow horizontally and controls that should. Why am I getting the other way around?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I am trying to build, using Auto Layout on **OS X** (not iOS!), a form-like container view: it right-aligns (in LTR layouts, as per OS X convention) labels next to controls, and the controls should grow horizontally to fit the width allocated to it by the superview (but not the labels). In graphical form:

[image: Example of what I want]

(The image tries to explain what is going on; here is a more detailed explanation.)

So far, what I've tried doing is:

1. string the controls vertically in the obvious way
2. pin the right edge of each control to the right edge of the form view
3. put the appropriate amount of space between each control and its label
4. make sure all controls have the same width
5. attach the labels to the left edge of the form view using an inequality relationship to allow extra space to the left

In each case, the labels hug their content with required priority in both dimensions, and the controls hug weakly in their horizontal direction.

When that produced the results below, I tried this:

5. place the labels in their own superviews, pinning to the top, right, and bottom and attaching to left with an inequality
6. make all labels the same width
7. pin them to the left edge of the form view

(Substitute "leading" and "trailing" for "left" and "right"; this should work properly on RTL systems as well.)

However, with both approaches, I get this:

[image: Result]

Notice how the controls stay at their minimum size while the labels stretch (and since the labels hug, extra space appears on the left side of the window instead).

What am I doing wrong? I'm completely lost here.

This is on OS X 10.11, but I target 10.8.

Thanks!

```
// 7 june 2016
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NSLayoutConstraint *mkConstraint(id view1, NSLayoutAttribute attr1, NSLayoutRelation relation, id view2, NSLayoutAttribute attr2, CGFloat multiplier, CGFloat c, NSString *desc);
NSTextField *newLabel(NSString *str);

@interface formChild : NSView
@property (strong) NSView *view;
@property (strong) NSTextField *label;
@property BOOL stretchy;
@property (strong) NSLayoutConstraint *baseline;
@property (strong) NSLayoutConstraint *leading;
@property (strong) NSLayoutConstraint *trailing;
@property (strong) NSLayoutConstraint *top;
@property (strong) NSLayoutConstraint *bottom;
- (id)initWithLabel:(NSTextField *)l;
- (void)onDestroy;
@end

@interface formView : NSView {
    NSMutableArray *children;
    BOOL padded;
    uintmax_t nStretchy;

    NSLayoutConstraint *first;
    NSMutableArray *inBetweens;
    NSLayoutConstraint *last;
    NSMutableArray *widths;
    NSMutableArray *leadings;
    NSMutableArray *middles;
    NSMutableArray *trailings;
}
- (id)init;
- (void)onDestroy;
- (void)removeOurConstraints;
- (CGFloat)paddingAmount;
- (void)establishOurConstraints;
- (void)append:(NSString *)label c:(NSView *)c stretchy:(BOOL)stretchy;
- (void)setPadded:(BOOL)p;
@end

@implementation formChild

- (id)initWithLabel:(NSTextField *)l
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    if (self) {
        self.label = l;
        [self.label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.label setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityRequired forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal];
        [self.label setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityRequired forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];
        [self addSubview:self.label];

        self.leading = mkConstraint(self.label, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
            NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual,
            self, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm label leading");
        [self addConstraint:self.leading];
        self.trailing = mkConstraint(self.label, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            self, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm label trailing");
        [self addConstraint:self.trailing];
        self.top = mkConstraint(self.label, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            self, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm label top");
        [self addConstraint:self.top];
        self.bottom = mkConstraint(self.label, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            self, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm label bottom");
        [self addConstraint:self.bottom];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)onDestroy
{
    [self removeConstraint:self.trailing];
    self.trailing = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:self.top];
    self.top = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:self.bottom];
    self.bottom = nil;

    [self.label removeFromSuperview];
    self.label = nil;
}

@end

@implementation formView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    if (self != nil) {
        self->padded = NO;
        self->children = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->nStretchy = 0;

        self->inBetweens = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->widths = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->leadings = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->middles = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->trailings = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)onDestroy
{
    formChild *fc;

    [self removeOurConstraints];
    [self->inBetweens release];
    [self->widths release];
    [self->leadings release];
    [self->middles release];
    [self->trailings release];

    for (fc in self->children) {
        [self removeConstraint:fc.baseline];
        fc.baseline = nil;
        [fc.view removeFromSuperview];
        fc.view = nil;
        [fc onDestroy];
        [fc removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self->children release];
}

- (void)removeOurConstraints
{
    if (self->first != nil) {
        [self removeConstraint:self->first];
        [self->first release];
        self->first = nil;
    }
    if ([self->inBetweens count] != 0) {
        [self removeConstraints:self->inBetweens];
        [self->inBetweens removeAllObjects];
    }
    if (self->last != nil) {
        [self removeConstraint:self->last];
        [self->last release];
        self->last = nil;
    }
    if ([self->widths count] != 0) {
        [self removeConstraints:self->widths];
        [self->widths removeAllObjects];
    }
    if ([self->leadings count] != 0) {
        [self removeConstraints:self->leadings];
        [self->leadings removeAllObjects];
    }
    if ([self->middles count] != 0) {
        [self removeConstraints:self->middles];
        [self->middles removeAllObjects];
    }
    if ([self->trailings count] != 0) {
        [self removeConstraints:self->trailings];
        [self->trailings removeAllObjects];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)paddingAmount
{
    if (!self->padded)
        return 0.0;
    return 8.0;
}

- (void)establishOurConstraints
{
    formChild *fc;
    CGFloat padding;
    NSView *prev, *prevlabel;
    NSLayoutConstraint *c;
    NSLayoutRelation relation;

    [self removeOurConstraints];
    if ([self->children count] == 0)
        return;
    padding = [self paddingAmount];

    // first arrange the children vertically and make them the same width
    prev = nil;
    for (fc in self->children) {
        if (prev == nil) {          // first view
            self->first = mkConstraint(self, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
                NSLayoutRelationEqual,
                fc.view, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
                1, 0,
                @"uiForm first vertical constraint");
            [self addConstraint:self->first];
            [self->first retain];
            prev = fc.view;
            prevlabel = fc;
            continue;
        }
        // not the first; link it
        c = mkConstraint(prev, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            fc.view, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
            1, -padding,
            @"uiForm in-between vertical constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->inBetweens addObject:c];
        // and make the same width
        c = mkConstraint(prev, NSLayoutAttributeWidth,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            fc.view, NSLayoutAttributeWidth,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm width constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->widths addObject:c];
        c = mkConstraint(prevlabel, NSLayoutAttributeWidth,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            fc, NSLayoutAttributeWidth,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm label width constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->widths addObject:c];
        prev = fc.view;
        prevlabel = fc;
    }
    relation = NSLayoutRelationEqual;
    if (self->nStretchy != 0)
        relation = NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual;
    self->last = mkConstraint(prev, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        1, 0,
        @"uiForm last vertical constraint");
    [self addConstraint:self->last];
    [self->last retain];

    // now arrange the controls horizontally
    for (fc in self->children) {
        c = mkConstraint(self, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            fc, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm leading constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->leadings addObject:c];
        c = mkConstraint(fc, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            fc.view, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
            1, -padding,
            @"uiForm middle constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->middles addObject:c];
        c = mkConstraint(fc.view, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            self, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
            1, 0,
            @"uiForm trailing constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->trailings addObject:c];
    }

    // we don't arrange the labels vertically; that's done when we add the control since those constraints don't need to change (they just need to be at their baseline)
}

- (void)append:(NSString *)label c:(NSView *)c stretchy:(BOOL)stretchy
{
    formChild *fc;
    NSLayoutPriority priority;
    NSLayoutAttribute attribute;
    uintmax_t oldnStretchy;

    fc = [[formChild alloc] initWithLabel:newLabel(label)];
    fc.view = c;
    fc.stretchy = stretchy;
    [fc setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:fc];

    [self addSubview:fc.view];

    // if a control is stretchy, it should not hug vertically
    // otherwise, it should *forcibly* hug
    if (fc.stretchy)
        priority = NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
    else
        // LONGTERM will default high work?
        priority = NSLayoutPriorityRequired;
    [fc.view setContentHuggingPriority:priority forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];
    // make sure controls don't hug their horizontal direction so they fill the width of the view
    [fc.view setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal];

    // and constrain the baselines to position the label vertically
    // if the view is a scroll view, align tops, not baselines
    // this is what Interface Builder does
    attribute = NSLayoutAttributeBaseline;
    if ([fc.view isKindOfClass:[NSScrollView class]])
        attribute = NSLayoutAttributeTop;
    fc.baseline = mkConstraint(fc.label, attribute,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        fc.view, attribute,
        1, 0,
        @"uiForm baseline constraint");
    [self addConstraint:fc.baseline];

    [self->children addObject:fc];

    [self establishOurConstraints];
    if (fc.stretchy) {
        oldnStretchy = self->nStretchy;
        self->nStretchy++;
        if (oldnStretchy == 0)
            [self establishOurConstraints];
    }

    [fc release];       // we don't need the initial reference now
}

- (void)setPadded:(BOOL)p
{
    CGFloat padding;
    NSLayoutConstraint *c;

    self->padded = p;
    padding = [self paddingAmount];
    for (c in self->inBetweens)
        [c setConstant:-padding];
    for (c in self->middles)
        [c setConstant:-padding];
}

@end

// demo

NSTextField *newPasswordField(void);
NSTextField *newSearchField(void);
NSButton *newCheckbox(NSString *label);

@interface appDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong) NSWindow *w;
@property (strong) formView *form;
@end

@implementation appDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSView *contentView;
    formView *form;
    NSButton *cb;

    self.w = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
        defer:YES];
    contentView = [self.w contentView];

    self.form = [formView new];
    [self.form setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [contentView addSubview:self.form];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self.form, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        1, -20,
        @"content view leading")];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self.form, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
        1, -20,
        @"content view top")];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self.form, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        1, 20,
        @"content view trailing")];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self.form, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        1, 20,
        @"content view bottom")];

    [self.form append:@"Password Field"
        c:newPasswordField()
        stretchy:NO];
    [self.form append:@"Search Box"
        c:newSearchField()
        stretchy:NO];
    cb = newCheckbox(@"Padded");
    [self.form append:@""
        c:cb
        stretchy:NO];
    [cb setTarget:self];
    [cb setAction:@selector(onToggled:)];

    [self.w visualizeConstraints:[self.form constraints]];
    [self.w makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}

- (IBAction)onToggled:(id)sender
{
    [self.form setPadded:([sender state] == NSOnState)];
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)app
{
    return YES;
}

@end

int main(void)
{
    NSApplication *a;

    a = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [a setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    [a setDelegate:[appDelegate new]];
    [a run];
    return 0;
}

// boilerplate

NSLayoutConstraint *mkConstraint(id view1, NSLayoutAttribute attr1, NSLayoutRelation relation, id view2, NSLayoutAttribute attr2, CGFloat multiplier, CGFloat c, NSString *desc)
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
        attribute:attr1
        relatedBy:relation
        toItem:view2
        attribute:attr2
        multiplier:multiplier
        constant:c];
    // apparently only added in 10.9
    if ([constraint respondsToSelector:@selector(setIdentifier:)])
        [((id) constraint) setIdentifier:desc];
    return constraint;
}

NSTextField *finishNewTextField(NSTextField *t, BOOL isEntry)
{
    [t setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSRegularControlSize]]];

    // THE ORDER OF THESE CALLS IS IMPORTANT; CHANGE IT AND THE BORDERS WILL DISAPPEAR
    [t setBordered:NO];
    [t setBezelStyle:NSTextFieldSquareBezel];
    [t setBezeled:isEntry];

    [[t cell] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
    [[t cell] setScrollable:YES];

    [t setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    return t;
}

NSTextField *newPasswordField(void)
{
    return finishNewTextField([[NSSecureTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect], YES);
}

NSTextField *newSearchField(void)
{
    NSSearchField *s;

    s = (NSSearchField *) finishNewTextField([[NSSearchField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect], YES);
    [s setSendsSearchStringImmediately:NO];
    [s setSendsWholeSearchString:NO];
    [s setBordered:NO];
    [s setBezelStyle:NSTextFieldRoundedBezel];
    [s setBezeled:YES];
    return s;
}

NSTextField *newLabel(NSString *str)
{
    NSTextField *tf;

    tf = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [tf setStringValue:str];
    [tf setEditable:NO];
    [tf setSelectable:NO];
    [tf setDrawsBackground:NO];
    return finishNewTextField(tf, NO);
}

NSButton *newCheckbox(NSString *label)
{
    NSButton *c;

    c = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [c setTitle:label];
    [c setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    // doesn't seem to have an associated bezel style
    [c setBordered:NO];
    [c setTransparent:NO];
    [c setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSRegularControlSize]]];
    [c setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    return c;
}
```

Comment: How wide do you want the text fields to be?  Have you considered setting them to a specific width, or perhaps a percentage of the width of their superview?

Comment: I want them to be as wide as the superview minus the width of the longest label.

Comment: I would probably add a constraint that pinned them to the leading side of the superview (or width equal to superview), and put it at a lower priority than the one pinning it to the label (999 instead of 1000, for example).  Then just make sure the content compression resistance priority of the label is 1000.

Comment: That works, but I'm not sure why. What's going on/what do I not understand? Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: I'll make a proper answer and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the result you are getting is because the text field has no reason to be bigger than it is in your screenshot given the constraints you've described.  When dealing with auto layout, if you get a result that you don't expect, it's often good to ask yourself why it *shouldn't* be like it is.

One mistake I regularly see from students and colleagues who are learning Auto Layout for the first time is that inequalities provide some indication of what size you actually are hoping something will be.  Simply providing a >= 10 inequality on the leading edge doesn't make it try and be == 10, for example.

To fix your layout, you'll need to provide a constraint that gives the text field a reason to be as wide as you want it to be.  There are obviously a lot of ways to do this, but one straight forward way is to add constraints that try and make the text field the full width of the superview at a lower priority than your other constraints (so, leading edge equal to leading edge of superview at 999 priority, or width equal to width of superview at 999 priority).

This will make the system attempt to make them as large as the superview, but only as much as it can while also respecting the other higher priority constraints you have in place (including content hugging / compression resistance).

Comment: All right, that makes sense. Thanks! I'll keep the advice in mind; hopefully it'll be useful again soon.